# proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup *******: no such host

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, ready-api

I do have proxy settings in place for both http nd https as part of docker proxies settings.

```
us002-*******:8080
```

I am trying to pull an image for ReadyaPI for a particular version and i keep getting the error below.

[image: docker pull error]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in docker container. After check out I found that I set the proxy server by setting environment variables `https_proxy` and `http_proxy`. After I unset both environment variables the issue disappeared.